# Root Owns Home Directory, chown does not work

Tags: mount, permissions, home-directory, chown, ownership

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and having various problems.  I have traced it back to the fact that my user's home directory (/home/user) is owned by root.

The /home directory is actually mounted on another drive, but I can see that in fstab I am mounting only /home and not /home/user:

```
UUID=DC56D19E56DX3233 /home ntfs user,exec 0 2
```

The chown command below does not seem to work:

```
sudo chown -R user /home/user
```

This will run without errors, however it does not actually change ownership of the direcory.  Here is the output of `ls -ld` after running the command:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20480 Sep 25 00:07 /home/user
```

This is the same as it was previously.

Comment: Can you add the relevant line from your `/etc/fstab` and/or the output of the `mount` command for your home partition (e.g. `mount | grep 'home'`?

Comment: `mount | grep home` -> /dev/sdb1 on /home type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab` -> UUID=DC56D19E56DX3233   /home       ntfs    user,exec       0       2

Comment: So the underlying issue would seem to be that you are using a non-linux filesystem (ntfs) for your home partition - which does not really support *nix style file permissions. It may be possible to make it work with a suitable file mask options on the mount but I don't have any experience of doing that. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, you have mounted your /home as a windows filesystem which is not a supported configuration.

Comment: This is a bug and should be fixed, moreso because it can easily be fixed.  have a look at the output from my terminal.  
Sorry but the Markdown help is not sufficiently clear as to how to insert a newline.  
    `gabe@server:/data$ ls -l RepairingGRUB.pdf`
    `-rwxrwxrwx 1 gabe gabe 76485 Mar 22 03:04 RepairingGRUB.pdf`
    `gabe@server:/data$ sudo chown -v root:root RepairingGRUB.pdf`
    `changed ownership of ‘RepairingGRUB.pdf’ from gabe:gabe to root:root`
    `gabe@server:/data$ ls -l RepairingGRUB.pdf`
    `-rwxrwxrwx 1 gabe gabe 76485 Mar 22 03:04 RepairingGRUB.pdf]`
---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue, as mentioned in the comments, was that my home directory was mounted on a different hard drive with an NTFS filesystem.

I backed up my home directory with Deja Dup to an external drive. Then used gparted to format the internal NTFS drive and change the filesystem to EXT4.

Next I changed /etc/fstab to match the new UUID of the drive and changed "ntfs" to "ext4".

After restart, I had to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to login in a terminal. I was there able to use sudo chown -R user:user /home/user.

I was then able to login to the GUI, and restore my home directory using Deja Dup and the backup on my external drive.

So far, everything is working great.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem but I want the folder to be also accessible from windows. As I am the only user I will change  the owner:group of the whole partition as per Mactrent's answer.

Answer (score 18):

NTFS doesn't support Unix-style 'owners', so the Linux kernel is forced to assign an owner for the entire volume - normally, root.  As an alternative to moving your entire home directory to EXT4, you could also give ownership of the entire partition to a specific user or group using the 'uid' or 'gid' options for `mount` (or in `fstab`).  There are security implications in a multi-user environment, but I used this method on my dual-boot laptop.

A long way inside the man page for `mount` (`man mount`), we find this under filesystem-specific options for NTFS:
`uid=value, gid=value and umask=value`
`Set  the  file permission on the filesystem.  The umask value is given in octal.  By default, the files are owned by root and not readable by somebody else.`

Your line in `fstab` would then be changed to `UUID=DC56D19E56DX3233 /home ntfs user,exec,uid=username,gid=group 0 2`, and you'd be free to edit the umask if you wanted.